# CSS first child element match, not any child element match

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I match the first element type of a parent element without matching that child element if it is not the first child?

I need a CSS selector that matches the first child element if it is a `header` element of the `body` parent element:

```
<body><header>
```

But I can not have the selector match the `header` element if it is not the *first* child of the `body` element:

```
<body><div></div><header>
```

Comment: `body + header`, then?

Comment: @MarcB Nope, that is if they are beside each other.

Comment: Maybe a combination with `:nth-of-type(1)`...?

Comment: @John It's `:first-of-type` probably... see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're simply looking for [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child).

```css
body > header:first-child {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Should match</header>
</body>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <header>Shouldn't match</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked after your edits and no, it was the combination I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't modify the CSS selector, I simply added the examples.

Comment: As it turns out complications with localhost SSL, 129 redirecting to 127, PHP not saying in the correct path, yaddah yaddah yaddah it was originally working. Thank you again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Other than this, You can also use `nth-child(1)`. Below snippet will work since *header* is the first child of parent *body*

```css
body > header:first-child {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header 1</header>
</body>
```

This will not work as *div* is the first child of the parent element:

```css
body > header:first-child {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <header>Header 1</header>
</body>
```

Comment: nth-of-type(1) will match the header in the second example. That's precisely the difference between child and of-type.

Comment: Hehe, Nice find. Thanks! :) Edited.

Answer (score -2):

```
body header:first-of-type:not(nth-child(n+2)) { background: black; }
```

Comment: That matches *any* generation `header` of the `body`.

Comment: I like it, creative though a bit more verbose than the combination selector I chose, thank you.

Comment: This selector is unreasonable.

Comment: So are you, lighten up.

Comment: Not sure "unreasonable" is the right choice of word there - but it's needlessly verbose. :not(:nth-child(n+2)) can be simplified to :first-child, and :first-of-type:first-child can be simplified to :first-child because the first child is, by definition, the first of its type within its parent (since *no other element* precedes it). There is yet one more subtle difference between body header:first-child and body > header:first-child - the former will match headers that aren't children of body, such as when a header is a child of a section instead, which means it can match more than one element.